# Double Filter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to "stack" filters in excel, so to speak.  I want to filter column A to show anything greater than 30 and then I want to filter column B to show the top ten items.  When I do this, however, it shows me all rows that fit both criteria (only five records).  I want to first fit the criteria for column A and then filter these results to show the top ten items in column B (10 records total).  I know that I could just copy the rows from my first filter to a new sheet and then filter the new worksheet, but is there any way to apply both filters so that I don't physically have to delete records this way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sort by Column B in Z->A sequence.  Then the top 10 will appear at the top.

Depending on what you want to do next you could then just look at or select the top 10, hide the other rows, or filter on the value of the 11th row.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  This is probably the best approach available to me.  Thanks for your response.